# SwiftUI CorevData: get a single bit of data in a attribute from a data model

Tags: swift, swiftui, core-data

i'm new to core data and i am trying to get one bit of data that has been inputted from an attribute as i'm trying to create a very basic login/sign up system and check if the user inputted email and password, once they have signed up, are in the same row when they try to login.
my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: []) var userDetails:  FetchedResults<UserDetails>
    @State private var username: String = ""
    @State private var passwords: String = ""
    @State private var name: String = ""
    @State private var attemptusername: String = ""
    @State private var attemptpasswords: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List(userDetails) { UserDetails in
                Text(UserDetails.email ?? "Unknown")
            }
            List(userDetails) { UserDetails in
                Text(UserDetails.password ?? "Unknown")
            }
            TextField("Email Address", text: $username)
            TextField("Password", text: $passwords)
            TextField("Name", text: $name)
            Button("Sign Up"){
                let userDetails = UserDetails(context: moc)
                userDetails.id = UUID()
                userDetails.email = "\(username)"
                userDetails.password = "\(passwords)"
                userDetails.name = "\(name)"
                
                try? moc.save()
            }
            TextField("Enter Email Address", text: $attemptusername)
            TextField("Enter Password", text: $attemptpasswords)
            
        }

    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FH9Tf.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FH9Tf.png)
```

i noral uses python so i tried to using
if userDetails.email[0] == attempedemail && userDetails.email[0] == attempedpassword {
userpage() } else {
Text("Failed") }
and then i could just loop that for how many inputs are done by the users

Comment: Not sure what you’re asking about really, do you want to check if the given username already exists? Why do you have two fields each for entering username and password? And why do you display existing usernames and passwords in separate lists?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, sorry english is not my first language, i'm trying to say that i want to check that both the given username and passwords exist and were created at the same time so they are the same email and password for each account